# Adding two polynomials stored as linked lists

Tags: java, linked-list, polynomial-math

I have the following code..

```
    import java.io.*;
    class Link

    {

      public int coeff;

      public int exp;

      Link next;

      public Link(int a,int b)
    {
       coeff=a;exp=b;
    }

       public int retcof(){
        return coeff;
    }

       public int retexp() {
        return exp;
    }

       public void displayLink(){
       System.out.print(coeff+"x^"+exp);
    }


    }


     class LinkList{


     Link first,last;


    public LinkList(){
               ;
    }

      public void insertfirst(int x,int y)
    {
      Link newLink=new Link(x,y);

      newLink.next=first;

      first=newLink;
    }

      public void displayList()
    {

      Link x=first;


      while(x!=null)
    {


      x.displayLink();

         x=x.next;

          if(x!=null)

          System.out.print("+");

    }



    }


      /*public void add(LinkList a,LinkList b)

      {
      int p;

      Link current1=a.first;

      Link current2=b.first;

      LinkList qwe=new LinkList();

      while(current2!=null)

      { 

      while(current1!=null)

      { 
       if(current1.retexp()>current2.retexp()) 

        qwe.insertfirst(current1.retcof(),current1.retexp());
       else if(current2.retexp()>current1.retexp())

        qwe.insertfirst(current2.retcof(),current2.retexp());
       else if(current1.retexp()==current2.retexp())

       { 

       p=current1.retcof()+current2.retcof();


     qwe.insertfirst(p,current2.retexp());

       }

         current1=current1.next;



      }

        current2=current2.next;


      }

      qwe.displayList();

      }*/


 public void add(LinkList a,LinkList b)
{
Link current1=a.first;

  Link current2=b.first;

  LinkList qwe=new LinkList();
while (current1 != null || current2 != null) {    
    //now check if one of them has ended    
   if (current1 == null&&current2!=null) //first ended; insert remaining nodes from second; return result    
     {qwe.insertfirst(current2.retcof(),current2.retexp());current2 = current2.next;}
  if (current2 == null&&current1!=null) //second ended, insert remaining nodes from first; return result  
    {qwe.insertfirst(current1.retcof(),current1.retexp());  current1 = current1.next;}
   //otherwise, compare exponents    
   if ((current1 != null && current2 != null)&&(current1.retexp() > current2.retexp())) 
      {qwe.insertfirst(current1.retcof(),current1.retexp()); current1 = current1.next;}    
       //advance the first pointer, but not he second        
   else if ((current1 != null && current2 != null)&&(current1.retexp() < current2.retexp()))   
       {qwe.insertfirst(current2.retcof(),current2.retexp()); current2 = current2.next;}
      //in this case advancing the second pointer, but not the first    
   else if((current1 != null && current2 != null)&&(current1.retexp() == current2.retexp()))//exponents are equal    
       {qwe.insertfirst(current2.retcof()+current1.retcof(),current2.retexp());; current1 = current1.next; current2 = current2.next;}    
      //add the members and advance both pointers    
}
qwe.displayList();
}





    }

      class zz
    {


      public static void main(String [] args)throws IOException
    {

       int degree1,degree2,num1,itr;


        LinkList wow=new LinkList();


        LinkList wow1=new LinkList();

    //wow.insertfirst(1,2);


      System.out.println("Enter the degree of the first polynomial "+" ");


      DataInputStream X=new DataInputStream(System.in);


      String s=X.readLine();

      degree1=Integer.parseInt(s);


      itr=degree1;


      while(itr>=0){ 

      System.out.print("enter the coeff of x^"+itr+" : ");

       s=X.readLine();
       num1=Integer.parseInt(s);

       wow.insertfirst(num1,itr);

       itr--;

      } 


      wow.displayList();


      System.out.println("\n"+"Enter the degree of the second polynomial "+" ");


      s=X.readLine();

      degree2=Integer.parseInt(s);

      itr=degree2;


      while(itr>=0)
    {

      System.out.print("enter the coeff of x^"+itr+" : ");

      s=X.readLine();
      num1=Integer.parseInt(s);

      wow1.insertfirst(num1,itr);
     itr--;

    }


      wow1.displayList();


      System.out.println("\n");


      wow.add(wow,wow1);

    }

    }
```

EDIT:FIXED. There was problem with the add() function which has been rectified now!

Is there any other efficient way to do this? How to make this code simpler particularly the add() function which seems a bit complex.

Comment: Which line is line 140?

Comment: @Ryan J I have no idea. That's what the compiler keep saying. The above code is all I have

Comment: What IDE are you using?

Comment: Most modern IDE's and text editors support line numbering. Unless it's Notepad. Please say you're not using Notepad... Turn on line numbering.

Comment: @ pbabcdefp JRE/JDK just the compiler. i wrote it into the notepad an then compiled in the terminal.

Comment: @ Ryan J Line numbering is on already in the notepad!

Comment: @user4275686 then you should be able to tell me what line 140 is.

Comment: @Ryan J just before {degree2=Integer.parseInt(s);}..that's line 140

Comment: @user4275686 No, it's not. The stack trace shows your exception is on line 140, in the `add` method.

Comment: I've just pasted your code into IntelliJ and it immediately gave me warnings about the problems Ryan has found in the `add()` method. Do not use notepad. Download IntelliJ IDEA Community version (free). It will find loads of errors for you.

Comment: @RyanJ I have a total of 160 lines. 140 CAN'T POSSIBLY BE IN THE ADD FUNCTION.

Comment: @user4275686 Sorry to be so blunt, but I don't care what your editor tells you, the stack trace you posted (which is probably out of date based on your comments) doesn't lie. Regardless, the point is moot. Look at my answer and see if you can fix what I've pointed out. It's highly likely that's what's causing this NPE. (there may be more you uncover later)

Comment: @user4275686 I just ran your code. Ryan is right. The error is in the `add()` method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The biggest thing I see here is your lack of handling properly the case where either of your `current` variables are `null`, in a manner that will prevent a NPE (as you've seen)...

Your code, better formatted below has a couple issues regarding the handling of `null`

```
while (current1 != null || current2 != null) {    
   //now check if one of them has ended    
   if (current1 == null) //first ended; insert remaining nodes from second; return result    
   {
        qwe.insertfirst(current2.retcof(),current2.retexp());
        current2 = current2.next;
   }
   if (current2 == null) //second ended, insert remaining nodes from first; return result  
   {
        qwe.insertfirst(current1.retcof(),current1.retexp());  
        current1 = current1.next;
   }
   //otherwise, compare exponents    
   if (current1.retexp() > current2.retexp()) 
   {
        qwe.insertfirst(current1.retcof(),current1.retexp()); 
        current1 = current1.next;
   }    
   //advance the first pointer, but not he second        
   else if (current1.retexp() < current2.retexp())   
   {
        qwe.insertfirst(current2.retcof(),current2.retexp()); 
        current2 = current2.next;
   }
   //in this case advancing the second pointer, but not the first    
   else //exponents are equal                     
   {        
        qwe.insertfirst(current2.retcof()+current1.retcof(),current2.retexp());
        current1 = current1.next; 
        current2 = current2.next;
   }    
   //add the members and advance both pointers    
}
```

Consider the case where `current2` is `null`

Your code will correctly determine that it's null and enter your second `if` block, and advance `current1`.

However, you don't protect against the access of fields on `current2` in the subsequent `if` blocks, so you're going to eventually get a NPE, on:

```
 //otherwise, compare exponents    
if (current1.retexp() > current2.retexp())  // right here! you access current2, but it's null :(
```

You need to bypass all this logic if either of your links are `null` so you don't get into this mess.

Comment: ok, so first of all I have connected every if/else by else-if ladder. Second, for the last two else-if(after first rectification last else will remain else) I have included `(current1 != null && current2 != null)&&(current1.retexp() > current2.retexp())` in both of them. And that's it. It solved the problem. Thank you good sir.

Comment: Same problem persists.

Comment: I have reverted my if-else corrections. My new corrections are:the third if block `if ((current1 != null && current2 != null)&&(current1.retexp() > current2.retexp())) `  following else-if `else if ((current1 != null && current2 != null)&&(current1.retexp() < current2.retexp()))   ` and last one as well changed to else-if `else if((current1 != null && current2 != null)&&(current1.retexp() == current2.retexp()))//exponents are equal ` . It is still giving me the same error.

Comment: Further edits: first if `if (current1 == null&&current2!=null)`  second if `if (current2 == null&&current1!=null)` .Its working, for now!

Answer (score 0):

The following is the complete resolved code.

```
    import java.io.*;
class Link

{

  public int coeff;

  public int exp;

  Link next;

  public Link(int a,int b)
{
   coeff=a;exp=b;
}

   public int retcof(){
    return coeff;
}

   public int retexp() {
    return exp;
}

   public void displayLink(){
   System.out.print(coeff+"x^"+exp);
}


}


 class LinkList{


 Link first,last;


public LinkList(){
           ;
}

  public void insertfirst(int x,int y)
{
  Link newLink=new Link(x,y);

  newLink.next=first;

  first=newLink;
}

  public void displayList()
{

  Link x=first;


  while(x!=null)
{


  x.displayLink();

     x=x.next;

      if(x!=null)

      System.out.print("+");

}



}



public void add(LinkList a,LinkList b)
{

Link current1=a.first;


   Link current2=b.first;


  LinkList qwe=new LinkList();

  while (current1 != null || current2 != null) {    

   if (current1 == null&&current2!=null)

     {qwe.insertfirst(current2.retcof(),current2.retexp());current2 = current2.next;}
  if (current2 == null&&current1!=null)

    {qwe.insertfirst(current1.retcof(),current1.retexp());  current1 = current1.next;}

   if ((current1 != null && current2 != null)&&(current1.retexp() > current2.retexp())) 

      {qwe.insertfirst(current1.retcof(),current1.retexp()); current1 = current1.next;}    

   else if ((current1 != null && current2 != null)&&(current1.retexp() < current2.retexp()))   

       {qwe.insertfirst(current2.retcof(),current2.retexp()); current2 = current2.next;}

   else if((current1 != null && current2 != null)&&(current1.retexp() == current2.retexp()))//exponents are equal    

       {qwe.insertfirst(current2.retcof()+current1.retcof(),current2.retexp());; current1 = current1.next; current2 = current2.next;}    
}
qwe.displayList();
}





}

  class k
{


  public static void main(String [] args)throws IOException
{

   int degree1,degree2,num1,itr;


    LinkList wow=new LinkList();


    LinkList wow1=new LinkList();


  System.out.println("Enter the degree of the first polynomial "+" ");


  DataInputStream X=new DataInputStream(System.in);


  String s=X.readLine();

  degree1=Integer.parseInt(s);


  itr=degree1;


  while(itr>=0){ 

  System.out.print("enter the coeff of x^"+itr+" : ");

   s=X.readLine();
   num1=Integer.parseInt(s);

   wow.insertfirst(num1,itr);

   itr--;

  } 


  wow.displayList();


  System.out.println("\n"+"Enter the degree of the second polynomial "+" ");


  s=X.readLine();

  degree2=Integer.parseInt(s);

  itr=degree2;


  while(itr>=0)
{

  System.out.print("enter the coeff of x^"+itr+" : ");

  s=X.readLine();
  num1=Integer.parseInt(s);

  wow1.insertfirst(num1,itr);
 itr--;

}


  wow1.displayList();


  System.out.println("\n");


  wow.add(wow,wow1);

}

}
```